# Conditional looping in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I`ve a JSON object and a loop

```
JSONobj.en.item[.....]

function dipslayItmes ( language )
{
    ...
    for ( i = 0; i < JSONobj.en.item.length; i++ )
       document.write( JSONobj.en.item[i] );
    ...
}
```

How to make it use *language* insted of directly use *en* ?

Comment: Might want to store the items in a separate variable because scope lookups can be expensive `var items = JSONobj[language].item;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do `foo.bar`, you usually can do `foo["bar"]`. However, not only can you put strings in the brackets, you can also put other expressions. Therefore, you can use this:

```
function displayItems(language) {
    ...
    for(var i=0; i<JSONobj[language].item.length; i++) {
        document.write(JSONobj[language].item[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square bracket notation to use a string literal or value from a variable to reference a property:

```
function dipslayItmes ( language )
{
    ...
    for ( i = 0; i < JSONobj[language].item.length; i++ )
       document.write( JSONobj[language].item[i] );
    ...
}
```